# How to troubleshoot custom Keras layers

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm creating a model using Keras (I'm a beginner) and wrote a lambda function to randomly choose whether or not to flip the initial input layer.

This is the snippet that attempts to do so:

```
input_global = Input(shape=(2001,1))
flipped = Lambda(lambda x: keras.backend.reverse(x, axes=1) if np.random.random() < 0.5 else x, output_shape=(input_global.shape[1], input_global.shape[2]))(input_global)
```

My model compiles, yet logging messages like `print("Hello, world")` in the middle of the definition of the model only result in "Hello world" being logged once- not every time data goes into the model during training.

How do I know that my function did what I intended it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building a Keras model, you are building a graph of operations, and whenever you run input through your model, you are running your input through that graph of operations. In other words, you build a model once, and then you can run input through it as many times as you'd like.

Non-Keras functions will *not* be part of the graph, including operations like `print` or `np.random.random()`. You will need to use the Keras equivalents.

For `print`, use the function [`keras.backend.print_tensor`](https://keras.io/backend/#print_tensor).

For `np.random.random`, use the function [`keras.backend.random_uniform`](https://keras.io/backend/#random_uniform).

I think you did not intend to do this, but because you are using `np.random.random()` in your custom layer, that operation will be executed *only when you build the model*. It will not be run whenever you run data through your model. In other words, the layer will either *only reverse* the inputs, or it will *only return* the inputs. To get the random behavior I think you want, you need to use a Keras function (i.e., `keras.backend.random_uniform`). Using that Keras function will generate a random number every time you run your model.

To belabor the point, `np.random.random()` will be run once when you build the model, and in essence it will determine at build time what that layer will do (i.e., it will either only reverse the input, or it will only return the input unchanged). `keras.backend.random_uniform()`, on the other hand, will not generate a random number when you build the model, but instead it adds a random_uniform operation to the model, so every time data goes through the model, a random number will be drawn from a uniform distribution at that point.

Comment: Do you know specifically how that line could be edited? I tried if `keras.backend.random_uniform((1,1)) < 0.5 else x`, yet I don't think it liked the if else syntax

Comment: I figured it out: `flipped = Lambda(lambda x : tf.cond(keras.backend.random_uniform((1,1)) < 0.5, lambda: keras.backend.reverse(x, axes=1), lambda: x), output_shape=(input_global.shape[1], input_global.shape[2]))(input_global)`

Comment: Yes, that looks correct! By the way, if you are just starting out with Keras, you might want to use the [Keras within TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras). That will give you access to many cool things the TensorFlow team has been working on recently.

Comment: Minor note, you can use `keras.backend.random_uniform([])` to get a scalar. `keras.backend.random_uniform((1,1))` gives you a 1x1 array. But for the conditional statement, they both work.